# decrypt encfs on startup

Tags: scripts, encryption, startup, upstart, encfs

I would like to decrypt an EncFS "volume" on startup.
Usually I decrypt the volume like this :

```
cat "/home/user1/encfs.pw" | encfs -S /mnt/encryptedVolume /mnt/decryptedVolume
```

In `/etc/init` I have a `myService.conf` file :

```
start on startup
stop on shutdown
respawn

pre-start script
  cat "/home/user1/encfs.pw" | encfs -S /mnt/encryptedVolume /mnt/decryptedVolume
end script

exec /home/user1/myService
```

Without the pre-start section, myService starts okay.
With the pre-start section, it doesn't because as stated in documentation, if the script lines fail it exists.

My issue is that the script line works in a shell but not in this pre-start.

Can someone please help ?
Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Is */mnt/encryptedVolume* already mounted when the pre-start script runs? And I hope */home/user1/encfs.pw* is on another encrypted partition, or at least a removable drive you keep somewhere safe, otherwise it's in plain sight for anyone who gets access to your computer, right?

Comment: Try starting the service from a terminal: `initctl start myService`. What's the output? Are there any error messages?

Comment: Hi, Thanks your feedback.
You are right /mnt/encryptedVolume was not mounted yet (fstab).
I just added sleep 20 before the encfs call and it works !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(I guess my comment should be an answer...)*

I'm guessing "/mnt/encryptedVolume" is not mounted yet when the startup script is being run.

You could wait for a while to run the script until after the needed volume is mounted,

- using a `sleep 20` in the script.
- Or run the script after everything's "up" and mounted and you're logged in, running `initctl start myService` should work.